# Unusable colors in Delphi 11.3 and 12 live code templates

Tags: templates, delphi, editor, syntax-highlighting, delphi-12-athens

I have recently upgraded to Delphi 11.3, and working out the wrinkles.

One problem I have is with the live code templates that Delphi shows as you type. I usually leave this enabled as it can be helpful.

But in Delphi 11.3, with the Color SpeedSetting set to "Ocean", the highlighted template slots are unreadable, because it uses dark blue background ("highlight", or I guess "highdark"), and black for the text, instead of some reverse color like white for the "foreground" (ie: text).

Here's a screen cap:

[image]

How do I get control of that color? I couldn't find an item in the Custom color settings for template highlighting.

Editing to add:  The Color SpeedSetting "Visual Studio (TM)" has the same problem.

Edit 2: More research:

1. This unusable colors problem occurs for any theme with light background. I'm not sure if Delphi has some "light theme" flag on some themes, or it's working from the color of the background of some element, but they all seem to exhibit the problem.
2. The 3rd party Delphi IDE Theme Editor also doesn't have an item for live template color.
3. The template field color was not a problem in 10.x, where the live template fields were drawn with an outline box, not a background change. (Well, the initial field has a background change, but changes to a box once you start typing.)
4. I have posted this to Quality Portal, RSP-42312.
5. Dec 2023 I updated issue RSP-42312 to report that the issue continues in Delphi 12 editor.

Comment: I find these templates sooo buggy. Delphi's templates had this annoying bug for years, and I found it's still there in Delphi 12 (well, of course I am going to turn it off, I've just installed the latest version). If you type "raise" and the IDE puts in the rest:  "Exception.Create('error message')" If you don't want to fill it and press Escape, you can't actually delete that line!!! You have to reopen the editor. How has this not been noticed for years? Things like that makes me wonder just wth has been going on over there - they have not enough money? no devs? no testers? Weird company

Comment: @TByte this "bug" you describe probably has not been fixed because it has not been reported (did you?). And I can't reproduce it in Delphi 12 either (just tried it right now). So maybe it has not been fixed because there is no bug in general but only in your particular setup? Instead of complaining file a bug report giving details and steps to reproduce.

Comment: @gwideman You claim the problem occurs with any theme with light background. That's not correct. It works fine with the "light" theme and the editor color speed setting "default". At least on my computer. I can reproduce it with the "Ocean" speed setting though.

Comment: @dummzeuch I know complaining isn't constructive and I've done a bit too much of it lately. I've been frustrated with bugs and taking it out on my beloved Delphi and seem to have lost compassion for a smaller guy like Embarcadero, but Delphi has given me so much - my career in fact, I should start reporting issues since I find them daily (I just do! I poke around and notice littlest of things, most of them are not really too horrible). It's just off-putting people writing that reported bugs don't get resolved (I should ignore such comments).  Still, I wish Emba had a much bigger team...

Comment: ...that focuses on quality, really dig, really get fussy about polishing the IDE.  I just get this crappy vibe from Emba sometimes.  And for some weird reason, I can't reproduce the bug I described even though it happens to me repeatedly.  Maybe there should be a community Quality Portal, where people vote on bugs/features they want fixed, allow discussion, a bit like here on stack? I want to just add this: I used Lazarus a while back, why is it that its editor feels more robust, responsive, useful? You have to admit Emba is being very complacent. VS editor seems lightyears ahead of Delphi's

Comment: and it's annoying, and I don't understand it. Which powers at Emba/Idera are denying Delphi the love it needs? So what if it won't make money or sound amazing on marketing, devs would appreciate it 1000x and that appreciation would come across, in subtle or slower ways maybe. It's been a long time since I sang Delphi's praises.

Comment: @TByte having recently used Visual Studio for writing a DLL to be used from Delphi, I wasn't that impressed with VS. But maybe that's because I didn't use it long enough to get used to it. As for a "Community Quality Portal": The current (about to be deprecated) Embarcadero QP does actually allow voting for bugs / feature requests and commenting.